# jQuery datatables - how to use filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to use https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter() but no effect.
I would like to filter column by clicking checkbox.

Code:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();

var filteredData = table
    .column( 0 )
    .data()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value > 4000 ? true : false;
    } );

$("#show_only_packed").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        filteredData.draw();
    }
});
```

Actually I used `search()` but I wanna understand how to use `filter()`

```
$("#show_only_packed").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        table.column( 3 ).search( 'Spakowano' ).draw();
    } else {
        table.column( 3 ).search('').draw();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

API method [`filter()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29) is often confused with [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29) but it doesn't affect the table. It only returns filtered data according to the given condition.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use [custom filtering](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) instead.

For example:

```
$('#show_only_packed').on('click', function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
         function (settings, data, dataIndex){
            return (data[0] > 4000) ? true : false;
         }
      );
   }

   table.draw();

   if(this.checked){
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();    
   }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0hggva3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for explain. What do you thing about my solution with `search`?
I've simplified it:
`$("#show_only_packed").click(function() {
        var table_filter = table.column( 3 ).search('').draw();

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            table_filter.search( 'Spakowano' ).draw();
        }
    });`

Comment: @user3041764, `search()` API method is good for text-based search (`search( 'Spakowano'`), for more complex scenarios, such as `data[0] > 4000` custom filtering should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `filter()` **should not** be confused with the `search()` function. The `filter()` actually **does not produce any direct output** on your table, but **can manipulate data behind the scenes**.

Suppose you have a list of people in your table with their age as one of the attributes. And your goal is to count the elder (over 60 years old) people in this set. Then this is easy using the filter like this:

```
var filteredData = table.column(3)
    .data()
    .filter(function (value, index) {
    if (parseInt(value) > 60) {
        eldersCount++;
    }
});
```

Here we define our age column to be column number 3 (zero based index), and we do our manipulations...

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anjeL2yy/1/)